# Diffusion of Ink in Water

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, diffusion, brownian-motion

I am investigating the diffusion of ink in water. A drop of blue ink is dropped to the center of a round plate of radius $R$. Say the drop of ink has an initial radius of $r=r_0$ (the very edge of the drop - there appears to be some "layers" in it), and I want to see how it spreads overtime (see image below).

[image: Ink spread in water: lab results (left) and illustration (right)]

My first try to fit a mathematical model for the results is by using the diffusion equation, $D\left(\frac{∂^2 ρ}{∂r^2}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{∂ρ}{∂r}\right)=\frac{∂ρ}{∂t}$, where $\rho$ is the ink's density and $D$ is the diffusion constant. Assuming an initial condition of $\rho(r,0)=\delta(r)$, the equation is solvable by separation of variables, and yields a Gaussian $ρ(r,t)=\frac{1}{4}πDt e^{-\frac{r^2}{4Dt}}$. However, this does not fit results well.

I found a very good fit to a function of form $r(t)=R-\frac{1}{at+b}$, for some constants $a,b>0$. It fits perfectly!

[image: ink in 40% water, 60% glycerol - fit for radius as function of time]

However, I have no theoretical explanation for it. I think it has more to do with the electrical interaction between the water and the ink. I tried to model it as a disc of water with uniform charge density $\sigma_w$, and as the ink spreads (isotropically), the electrical force from the outside ring of water gets weaker, as the ring of water narrows. The force should be in form of $F(r)\propto r^3=m\ddot{r}$ so that $r=R-\frac{1}{at+b}$ is a solution. Can anyone help with finding a theoretical explanation for this problem? Much appriciated!

Comment: When learning the diffusion equation, I remember my prof talked about ink diffusing on a piece of paper, not in water. Is the photograph from your experiment? While the deep blue part appears Gaussian-ish, the outer light blue ring does not. I wonder if the ink in water separates into two components that diffuse at different rates? A bit like chromatography? Not sure if that's useful, just a thought. When you measured the radius, did you measure up to the light blue ring?

Comment: This is a photo from the experiment. I measured the very end of the drop, i.e., the outer light blue. I have no detailed explanation for the layers that have formed, but this is for another time, I am interested particularly in the outer radius. Any ideas for a model that gives a solution of the form $r(t)=R-1/(at+b)$?

Comment: For a thin layer of water the diffusion will be [pseudo-two dimensional](http://rpdata.caltech.edu/courses/aph162/2006/Protocols/diffusion.pdf). // I'd also agree that the ink likely contains multiple chromophores.

Comment: @MaxW, the paper shows a solution in form of a Gaussian, $ρ(r,t)=\frac{1}{4}πDt e^{-\frac{r^2}{4Dt}}$, as I mentioned. This model does not fit well the results, as the diffusion is disturbed by the electric force of the water.

Comment: The paper says $ρ(r,t)=\frac{1}{4π(D-t)} e^{-\frac{r^2}{4D-t}}$

Comment: Would it be possible to see the Gaussian fit as well? Unfortunately I have no physical explanation, but I would say it's quite unlikely $r(t)$ takes a functional form that is not in agreement with the diffusion equation. Note Max's correction, I think that will work. Edit: having looked at the paper, is it not $\frac{1}{4\pi D t}\exp \left(- \frac{r^2}{4Dt} \right)$ ?

Comment: @MaxW Are you sure it is not supposed to be $\frac{1}{4\pi D t}$? The units don't seem to be right.

Comment: @Samalama, the Gaussian is supposed to spread according to $\sigma(t)=\sqrt{2Dt}$. However, the results look nothing like a square root. They do not look linear when I look at $r^2$.

Comment: Sorry it should be $ρ(r,t)=\frac{e^{-\frac{r^2}{4D-t}}}{(4πD)-t }$ // Remember the initial drop has a diameter too. You're not starting from 0.

Comment: @MaxW $D$ and $t$ does not have the same units. The paper you showed says it is exactly as I mentioned above (the math got a bit misplaced) - it is not a minus sign, but multiplication, i.e., $\rho(r,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi Dt} e^{-\frac{r^2}{4Dt}}$.

Comment: @RoyShtoyerman - !@#$%^ yes you are correct. I blew the image up and it isn't a minus sign but a dot for multiplication. Score one for good dimensional analysis!

Comment: @RoyShtoyerman Have you had a look at this paper? http://mitgcm.org/~edhill/Tracer_work/papers/ejp4_2_020.pdf ... I haven't read it, just looked at the figures. They plot $r^2$ vs $t$ and didn't observe perfectly linear data either (actually looked more like a square root relation to the eye?).

Comment: Again, remember the initial drop has a diameter too. You're not starting from r=0.

Comment: Yes, [this](http://mitgcm.org/~edhill/Tracer_work/papers/ejp4_2_020.pdf) paper you mentioned is the one I based my experiment on. I did not succeed in solving the equation they mentioned there (not even numerically), and I found another model that fits perfectly, but with no explanation for it (it does not solve the diffusion equation; and it does take the plate's radius into consideration.)

Comment: If $-\frac{r^2}{4Dt} \ll 1$ then $\exp{(-\frac{r^2}{4Dt})} \approx 1 - r^2/4Dt$

Comment: I agree with Samalama that a chromatography-like phenomenon could be occurring.  "Blue ink" is fairly likely to be made up of more than one chemical; the lighter the chemical the faster it moves, at the molecular level, with the same thermal energy.  Try leaving a strip of paper in rubbing alcohol or the like, and make a blue ink mark near the bottom of the paper (above the level of the alcohol).  As the alcohol evaporates and moves up, do you get multiple bands of different colors?  (Look up "paper chromatography" for more info)

Comment: Did you try what happens if in the system you did not have water? It looks like the ink is just spreading rather than diffusing.

Comment: @alarge The ink's spread is much, much slower when it's not in water.

Comment: Is it of the same functional form? Also, as this cannot be seen from a top-down picture: is the ink on top of the water, under it, or is it actually mixed in throughout? Did you experiment with different amounts of water?

Answer (score 1):

I find the hard edge (no fuzziness), close to perfect roundness and no apparent variation in colour tone (i.e. density) in the outer blue ring all unusual for typical diffusion... so I'm not surprised it doesn't fit the density equation.

Before proposing a new physical model, can you rule out any systemic errors, e.g. are you 100% sure there's not a structural limit to the edge of the ring? Are you 100%  sure you've observed diffusion and not maybe chromatography, or a different transport process? Maybe look into the components of the ink. These sound like silly questions, but things you should probably check before proposing a physical model different to the theory.

Comment: The residuals graph seems to be quite random. It appears to be so in all different water-glycerol concentrations I have tried. I am looking for a simple model that explains the spread of a uniformly electrically charged fluid (no fluid dynamics are really needed) upon a uniformly charged round disk. Is there some simple solution for it?

Comment: Is it valid to assume you're dealing with uniformly *charged* fluids and a disk? I would argue that macroscopically, there is no net charge and any electrostatic effects would occur on a microscopic scale. Have you considered surface tension, or gradients in surface tension? The Marangoni effect comes to mind. What is the frame rate of your captures?

Comment: I have thought about the Marangoni effect, however I don't know how to apply it here. Any concrete idea? I don't know if assuming uniform charge is reasonable, this is just one suggestion, I'd love to hear other suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps this paper is useful?  https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys4214 ... I would say it's unlikely to be a direct/macroscopic consequence of electromagnetism (of course microscopically, pretty much everything is EM). If you want to get to the bottom of this, I think you need to try and understand the chemistry of your ink better, what is causing it to separate like this, and also perhaps consider the role of surfactants (glycerol) in your water (the paper above discusses glycerol but maybe this is also useful https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0920410512002185 )

Comment: Another thing you might want to consider is the effect of the hard boundary of your dish. The diffusion equation assumes free space and you haven't imposed any boundary conditions when solving it. Your fitted function, however, includes $R$. So maybe, you need to think of a way to include $R$ in the density equation by imposing boundary conditions? [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.mit.edu/course/1/1.061/www/dream/FOUR/FOURTHEORY.PDF&ved=2ahUKEwjBjuH2sL3pAhVKhlwKHdBwAwYQFjACegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0Ti63OsTqKMFvlxOa9HCfW) might be a start.